# Does Harris corner detector and Harris interest points detector the same things?

Tags: computer-vision

I'm new in computer vision, but want to learn this area.
Now I read article ["On Space-Time Interest Points"](https://www.irisa.fr/vista/Papers/2005_ijcv_laptev.pdf). In chapter 2.1 author explains how find interest points in spatial domain, using Harris interest point detector. I try to find more deeply explanation about this method, but can find only Harris Corner Detector.
Are they the same things?

Comment: You might want to check out the reference that they have in the paper.

"_To detect spatio-temporal interest points, we build on
the idea of the Harris and F¨orstner interest point operators
(Harris and Stephens, 1988_"

_Harris, C. and Stephens, M. 1988. A combined corner and edge
detector. Alvey Vision Conference, pp. 147–152._

From just scanning through without actually reading in detail I think it is the same thing

Comment: This would be a better fit on http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the same thing. Harris is an interest point detector, which happens to detect corners. There are other corner detectors, such as "Good Feature to Track", FAST, Forstner, etc. There are also interest point detectors, which detect structures other than corners. For example the Difference-of-Gaussians (DoG) detector used by SIFT features detects blob-like structures.